# Heatmap classification

Tags: r

I have 2 tables:
table 1: rows- samples, columns- bacterias-  square in place (i,j) describes the frequency of the bacteria j in sample i.

[image]
image.png

table2 : rows- samples, columns- type (3 options: type1/type2/type3)

[image: image.png]

I have created an heatmap from the first table with this code:

```
heatmap<-pheatmap(data.for.heatmap2,color = brewer.pal(9,"Blues"),
             show_rownames = F, cluster_cols = F)
```

Now, I want to add the classification from the second table to the heatmap.
The classification is something like this:

[image]

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: [Can you please provide a reproducible example of your data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach to what you want:

After joining by rownames, we transform into long format then use geom_tile:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- left_join(rownames_to_column(table1), 
          rownames_to_column(table2), by="rowname") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("bact"))

ggplot(df, aes(name, rowname, fill= log(value), color = type)) + 
  geom_tile(size =1) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "gold"))+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have used : 'pheatmap'. I added a code to the question, not sure how to do the same as in pheatmap?